# Email based login system via REST

Tags: php, rest

I am working on a RESTFUL system and i want to create email based login system, i need to some advise and i want to know how should i separate controllers and how many controllers i need.
Here are my scenario :
1 - User enter his/her email in client
2 - RESTFUL application receive email
3 - RESTFUL application looking for email in database, if exist , update the token and send this token to user email, if email not exist in database, application insert email to database and create token for this email, and then application should send this token to user's email.
4 - user receive the email and click on the authorization link to log in.
5 - RESTFUL application process this link and grunt user if everything was ok

Answer (score 1):

You should have two end-points, i.e-two controllers for this:

**First End Point: /login**
The Login controller would handle both GET and POST requests.

So for GET it will return the client-view to the user, with the email in the form element.
When the user will submit that form, the form will be directed back to login controller with POST request. It will be here, when you would perform the operations in the point 3. [You can choose to have a separate utility file to perform DB-related functions and sending mails because it is not preferred to have lengthy operations in controller body]

**Second End Point: /authorize**
So this will be the link you send to the user. Let this authorize controller handle GET request only.
So when user visits this link, it should first verify the user and eventually grunt him and return a confirmation message or welcome message.

Hope this helps.